# MacBook Pro issue with local IP download over wifi

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, macbook-pro, webserver, http

I am facing a strange situation on my macbook pro, with my wifi adapter:

- I'm serving a file via http (whatever server I use, I get the same problem: apache, node.js, ...): [http://localhost:8080/myFile]
- When I try to download the file via [http://localhost:8080/myFile] or via [http://127.0.0.1:8080/myFile], it works flawlessly.
- Now when I try to access the same file, but this time via my local ip and from my machine [http://192.168.1.5:8080/myFile], **the download starts but stalls after ~60kbytes** ! This happens, no matter which file I serve, and no matter which server technique I use. I tried downloading with browsers (safari, chrome, firefox) and using command-line tools (wget, curl), and I always the same problem...
- Now, if I try to download the same file, using the same URL (i.e. the one with my local IP) but this time from a *distinct computer*, it works perfectly again... I am puzzled.
- Even stranger, if I try to do the same experiment, but this time with my ethernet adapter (and switching off my wifi adapter), I have absolutely no problem... meaning I can serve and download the file as expected, using either localhost or local ip url.
  So this issue seems to be related to my WiFi adapter.

I do not have any kind of firewall/little snitch/... installed and I checked my WiFi adapter configuration, there is nothing special there.

I tried turning off and on the wifi adapter, shutting down and restarting my mac, everything in vain.

In summary, I cannot download a file that is served locally via my WiFi adapter...

Any suggestion about why this might happen / how to push the diagnosis further / how to solve the issue?

Thanks

Comment: So, you're saying local loopback on your Wi-Fi interface stalls, but you can transfer the same file via your Wi-Fi interface to another machine, and it works? And other local loopback cases work? Sounds like a bug in your Wi-Fi driver, where it probably isn't freeing up frame buffers on the loopback code path. Does this test hose the Wi-Fi interface completely, or just that one transfer? Is this the built-in Wi-Fi card that came with your MBP? Exactly which MBP model is this? And exactly which version of OS X?

Comment: You are right, local loopback with my ip stalls, others work (localhost and 127.0.0.1). From another machine, no problem. It does not freeze my interface for other purposes, just the download itself. It is the builtin wifi adapter in my MBP (model 15-inch, Mid 2012, MacBookPro9,1). The wifi is an AirPort Extreme  (0x14E4, 0xF5), firmware version Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (5.106.98.100.22).

Comment: I am more tempted to think this is a software bug rather than a hardware one, maybe from something I installed and uninstalled. I have no idea.

Comment: Forgot to mention I am running Mavericks